# L2-normalization with Keras Backend?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lambda, model, normalization

I'd like to normalize the inputs going into my neural network but, as I'm defining my model in this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Davide Mori\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Dataset.csv')
print(df)


target_column = ['W_mag', 'W_phase']
predictors = list(set(list(df.columns)) - set(target_column))
X = df[predictors].values
Y = df[target_column].values

def get_model(n_inputs, n_outputs):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1000,input_dim= n_inputs, activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)))
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='linear', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.0001)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])
    model.summary()
    return model

n_inputs, n_outputs = X.shape[1], Y.shape[1]
model = get_model(n_inputs, n_outputs)
# fit the model on all data
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=1)
```

how do I apply the lambda layer to my inputs? Isn't wrong the commented line position? Because If I put the lambda layer there I'm normalizing what is already be "transformed" by the first hidden layer,right? How can I solve this problem?

This is the error I have when putting the lambda layer before everything else :

```
2020-10-12 15:08:46.036872: I 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports 
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 
2020.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, 
in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the 
script
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 
2020.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 
18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/Davide Mori/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/prova_rete_sfs.py", 
line 60, in <module>
model = get_model(n_inputs, n_outputs)
File "C:/Users/Davide Mori/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/prova_rete_sfs.py", 
line 52, in get_model
model.summary()
File "C:\Users\Davide Mori\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1302, in 
summary
raise ValueError('This model has not yet been built. '
ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by 
calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an 
`input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.
```

Comment: Why can't you put this Lambda layer as the first layer i.e. before Dense(1000)?

Comment: I've written the Traceback in the question. Please have a look

Comment: In this case before model.summary() you need to set the input size explicitly in build command ````model.build(n_inputs)````

Comment: writing that it send me an error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Your n_inputs should be a tuple. In case it is a digit try using ````model.build((n_inputs,))```` (nothing after comma)

Comment: Another error : `ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 1 dimensions. for 'lambda/l2_normalize/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [8], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1>.`

Comment: Haha. I don't know your real input shape :) Either do not set "axis" in your l2_normalize ````K.l2_normalize(x)```` or add a dimension to you input_shape e.g. ````model.build((1, n_inputs))````

Comment: The input shape is a (2025 ,8), where every sample is of 8 feature. Not putting the axis gives me the error : `ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [8]`

Comment: If this is the case, then this (2025,8) or vise versa should be set as parameter of ````model.build((2025,8))````

Comment: Thank you it finally worked! :)